# TypeError: json is not a function using handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I have a `js` file being used by handlebars:

```
    var fs = require('fs');

    function json(context) {
      return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(context), null, 2);
    }


    var myHelpers = {
      json_data: function() {
        return json(fs.readFileSync('file.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
      }
    };

let template = fs.readFileSync('tpl.hbs', { encoding: 'utf8' });
let result = dummyjson.parse(template, { helpers: helpers });
```

Getting error in line `return json(fs.readFileSync('file.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}));` saying `TypeError: json is not a function`

How would you fix that? and why it is happens?

Comment: Try removing `this.`?

Comment: What are you expecting to be `this` ? In your case `this` refers to myHelpers object.

Comment: Remove .this and it will work, just json()

Comment: I tried without `this` at first, same thing

Comment: The error is very simple and straighforwar: json function is not available. Make sure it's accessible to `json_data` and it will work.

Comment: Fron the code snippet that you have provided the json function is not defined anywhere

Comment: Do you have all of this code in the same js file for sure? If yes, it should work as it is... There must be some other reason outside the code you provided.

Comment: just updated the question, I am using handlebars, that is probably causing a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
  var fs = require('fs');

  function json(context) {
    return JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(context), null, 2);
  }

  var myHelpers = {
    json_data: function() {
      return this.json(fs.readFileSync('file.json', {encoding: 'utf8'}));
    }
  };

  myHelpers.json_data.bind(this,window);
```

> Here, `this` keyword is referencing towards your `myHelpers` instead of `window object`. So you need to `bind` it using `bind` method to point it to current `window`.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731601/typeerror-this-json-is-not-a-function#comment74506296_43731601

Comment: initially I didn't have `this`, the question being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK if all the lines are in one file as you said.